# How do I prevent caching on a website?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Within a website in development, we have it templated as a master page that contains the head of the webpage, then a header and body div that loads in content dynamically. Basically, I'm trying to prevent caching on all the pages loaded in dynamically.

Browsers would be IE8 onwards.

Comment: Do you want prevent the caching on the client or on server site?

Comment: Client-side would be what I'm looking for.

Comment: The simple answer is to use CTRL+F5 to force the browser to reload the page and ignore any cached data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said you should only be doing that if the website is in development or the content really needs to be loaded fresh every time. Internet Explorer supports some meta tags that can do what you need, specifically

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
```

[Click here for more information](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/234067)

If you ever want to test in firefox, you could try out [this plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cachetoggle/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Google Chrome to develop, there are an option that let you cache free when dev tools is open, but if you want a simple trick is just to pass a timestamp in a query string during your request. Something like:

```
http://localhost/path/to/project/?nocache=74567363
```

If you are using some framework that helps you to handle with the includes like AngularJS ou BackboneJS, make the redirects with:

```
var myUrl = 'http://localhost/path/to/project/?nocache=';
var timestamp = (new Date()).getTime();
window.location.href = myUrl + timestamp;
```